# How to properly embed Google Data studio report in Electron Js?

Tags: electron, looker-studio

I'm looking for a way to embed Google Data studio in Electron JS.

I've copied the Embed code from Data Studio, and pasted it into the body of the Electron app.

The app lunches correctly, however there is a massage in the renderer window:
"Can't access report
Your current account can't access this report, or the report doesn't exist."

I've added the same code to the body of a simple HTML and run live server in Visual Studio Code and it works correctly (the graphs are visible from Data Studio).

Does it need some form of special connection from Electron?

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue when embedding the report. You need to make sure that the **anyone on the internet can view** option is enabled in the **Manage access.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As Ajith mentioned, in order to successfully embed a Looker Studio report as an iFrame you will need to change the share settings of the report.

When you click on the Share button, you will need to select either

- Unlisted: Anyone on the internet with the link can view
- Public: Anyone on the internet with the link can find and view

and then make sure the share link is set to 'Viewer' instead of 'Editor' if you only want the report to be viewable in your embed.